# Insert and replace HTML Between two HTML tags bash

Tags: html, bash, shell

I have successfully parsed through an HTML document and pulled the elements I want from it using this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#  ParseHtml.sh
grep -o '<h2 .*>.*</h2>' Path/to/html/report.html | sed 's/\(<h2 .*>\|<\/h2>\)//g' > parseResults.txt
```

Here is the output from the above parse command:

```
<h2 id="test-count"><span class="number">1704</span> pass</h2>
<h2 id="fail-count"><span class="number">163</span> failures</h2>
```

What I am looking to do is take the output from the parsing command and insert and replace it between two `<BODY>` tags:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:bsh="jelly:beanshell" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">

<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->

<BODY>

<!--Insert and replace any pre-existing HTML --->

</BODY>

</j:jelly>
```

What command would I use to achieve this? I'm having trouble attempting to achieve this via sed. I would like to stick to a method that is within bash. Any help is greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways (at least when I understand right to question)

If you template file (lets call it `templ.html`) contains:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:bsh="jelly:beanshell" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">

<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->

<BODY>

<!--Insert and replace any pre-existing HTML --->

</BODY>

</j:jelly>
```

and your `parseResults.txt` contains

```
<h2 id="test-count"><span class="number">1704</span> pass</h2>
<h2 id="fail-count"><span class="number">163</span> failures</h2>
```

then the following `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
template=$(<templ.html)
results=$(<parseResults.txt)
echo "${template//<!--Insert and replace any pre-existing HTML --->/$results}"
```

produce

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:bsh="jelly:beanshell" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">

<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->

<BODY>

<h2 id="test-count"><span class="number">1704</span> pass</h2>
<h2 id="fail-count"><span class="number">163</span> failures</h2>

</BODY>

</j:jelly>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate your input. You are right, there are thousands of ways to do this. I will post my answer below how I achieved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #Begin html parse. Find all h2 tags with class info and strip them out. Find all span tags (ending in R in my case) and strip them out. Finally, write the parsed HTML into a file called "iOS_Unit_Test_Results.txt" (which is essentially just a sequence of numbers)

  grep -o '<h2 .*>.*</h2>' $dirpath/something/htmltoparse.html | sed 's/\(<h2 .*>\|<\/h2>\)//g' | grep -o 'r">.*<' | grep -o 'r">.*</span>' | sed 's/r">//' | sed 's/<\/span>//' > ~/.jenkins/email-templates/iOS_Unit_Test_Results.txt

    IFS=$'\n'
    s=0

    #Create variable to write beginning header information. 

    BEGINNING_HTML="<j:jelly xmlns:j=\"jelly:core\" xmlns:bsh=\"jelly:beanshell\" xmlns:st=\"jelly:stapler\" xmlns:d=\"jelly:define\">\n<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->\n<BODY>"

ENDING_HTML="</BODY>\n</j:jelly>"

MODIFY_HTML=""

#Loop through the sequenced number file from the HTML parse above

for number in $(cat ~/.jenkins/email-templates/iOS_Unit_Test_Results.txt); do
#If it's the very first element, than it's the total number of tests.
if [ $s -eq 0 ]; then

MODIFY_HTML="$MODIFY_HTML <h2>Number of Of Tests: $number </h2>\n"
echo $MODIFY_HTML
fi
#If its the second element, than it's the # of unit test failures. 
if [ $s -eq 1 ]; then

MODIFY_HTML="$MODIFY_HTML <h2>Number of Failures: $number </h2>\n"

echo $MODIFY_HTML

fi

s=$((s+1))

done
#Write html file by concatenating variables. 

printf "$BEGINNING_HTML\n$MODIFY_HTML\n$ENDING_HTML" > ~/.jenkins/email-templates/iphoneUnitTest.jelly
```